# docker buildx disable parallel build for multiplatform

Tags: docker, x86-64, arm64, buildx

I have a docker build that during the build needs to run the server for some admin configuration. By running the server it claims a port and during multi-platform build this conflicts with the `docker buildx` command as it claims that the port is already in use.

Now I would like to run the build sequentially instead of in parallel but that does not seem to be an option?

I've tried to make this work by setting the cpus  to 1 (`--cpuset-cpus 1`) but that does not seem to make a difference.

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 --cpuset-cpus 1 --push -t ivonet/payara .
```

- from git repo https://github.com/IvoNet/docker-payara
- I'm working on an Apple M1 (aarch64)

So is it possible to run this build with parallel disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bit of research on it now and I have not found a satisfactory answer other than that it does not seem to be possible at this time to disable the parallelism.

I did find a workaround that works for me and steps nicely around this issue.
I now use actual remote servers to build the target platforms I need.

In essence, one defines a remote (through ssh) server with docker installed on it and you configure it to build specific targets.
That way it can actually run in parallel as the physically different machines can handle the formally overlapping port number (as was the problem in my use case).

Read the full blog post on it [here](http://ivo2u.nl/Vq)

Comment: May be possible now with the buildkit `max-parallelism` option? https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/configure/#max-parallelism

Answer (score 0):

try `COMPOSE_PARALLEL_LIMIT=1`.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_parallel_limit

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a builder, you can pass this info:

`buildkitd.toml`

```
[worker.oci]
  max-parallelism = 1
```

when you are on local machine:

```
docker buildx create --use \
  --name mybuilder \
  --driver docker-container \
  --config <<dir>>/buildkitd.toml
```

when you are on github actions:

```bash
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
          config: <<dir>>/buildkitd.toml
```