# Docker BuildKit: Wait for local image to build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I have the following project structure

```
./docker/Base/Dockerfile
./docker/ServiceA/Dockerfile
./docker/ServiceB/Dockerfile
./docker-compose.yml
```

ServiceA and ServiceB share the same base image to avoid having stuff like package installation duplicated. The base Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
# Do stuff
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

The ServiceA and ServiceB Dockerfiles look like this:

```
FROM servicebase:latest
# Do different stuff
CMD /foo/service[A|B]
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, it is my goal to first build and tag the base image locally, and then build the image for services A and B.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  servicebase:
    image: servicebase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Base/Dockerfile
    container_name: servicebase
  serviceA:
    depends_on:
      - servicebase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/ServiceA/Dockerfile
  serviceB:
    depends_on:
      - servicebase
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/ServiceB/Dockerfile
```

The problem I face is that when I run `docker compose up`, the Docker BuildKit tries to parallelize the building of the images of ServiceA and ServiceB to the building of the base image. During the build of image of Service(A|B), `servicebase` therefore was not built yet, such that the builder then queries Dockerhub and fails, as `servicebase` is not on Dockerhub:

> Status: pull access denied for servicebase, repository does not
> exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the
> resource is denied, Code: 1

When I disable buildkit (`export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0`), which implies a sequential building process, everything works.

Obviously I am trying to achieve something that is not intended with BuildKit. Is there a fundamental flaw in my design or is there some configuration option for BuildKit I am missing? I don't want to publish `servicebase´ to Dockerhub.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker buildx disable parallel build for multiplatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797861/docker-buildx-disable-parallel-build-for-multiplatform)

Comment: @Paolo No, not really, since I don't want to disable parallelism but instead fix the build order.